# Iterating but not dereferencing invalid iterators in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This code invokes an assertion, when compiled in debug mode with Visual C++ compiler.

```
std::vector<int> test;
++test.begin();
```

The program says:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

...

Expression: vector iterator not incrementable.
```

As for me, this code is perfectly legal, since I am not going to dereference the iterator. The question: is this behavior undefined (or maybe implementation defined) by The Standard, or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, you're not allowed to take the `container.end()` and increment it.

In this case, because you have an empty container `container.begin() == container.end()` and so you can't increment `begin()` either.

You can find a citation for this in C++ 2011 Table 107. It basically says that `++iterator` is only valid if `iterator` is dereferenceable.

[image: A portion of C++ 2011 Table 107]

So this is legitimate undefined behavior.

Comment: But we are allowed to do anyting with an invalid pointer, until it is not going to be dereferenced. And this is definied behavior.

Comment: I understand. I commented your first answer. The citation explains everything, thank you.

Comment: @newbie: Arithmetic on an invalid pointer is also undefined behaviour. It's just less likely to cause a noticable error, since most processors treat pointers as numerical values and won't trap invalid pointers unless you dereference them.

Comment: @Angew: Whoops. Third try is the charm.